# Fastest way to extract hour from time (HH:MM)

Tags: r, time, data.table, hour

Wish `fastPOSIXct` works - but not working in this case.

Here is my time data (which does not have dates) - and I need to get the hours-part from them.

```
times <- c("9:46","11:06", "14:17", "19:53", "0:03", "3:56")
```

Here is the wrong output from `fastPOSIXct`:

```
fastPOSIXct(times, "GMT")
[1] "1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT" "1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"
[3] "1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT" "1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"
[5] "1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT" "1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"
```

It does not recognize the times without the presence of dates correctly.

The `hour` method from `data.table` with `as.ITime` solves the purpose, but looks like slow on large times arrays.

```
library(data.table)
hour(as.ITime(times))
# [1]  9 11 14 19  0  3
```

Wondering if there is some faster way (just like `fastPOSIXct`, but works without the need for date).

`fastPOSIXct` really works like snap, but just wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may also try `substr`: `as.integer(substr(vals, start = 1, stop = nchar(vals) - 3))`

---

In a benchmark on a vector with 10e6 elements, `stringi::stri_sub` is fastest, and `substr` number two.

```
vals <- sample(c("9:46", "11:06", "14:17", "19:53", "0:03", "3:56"), 1e6, replace = TRUE)

fun_substr <- function(vals) as.integer(substr(vals, start = 1, stop = nchar(vals) - 3))

grab.hrs <- function(vals) as.integer(sub(pattern = ":.*", replacement = "", x = vals))

fun_strtrim <- function(vals) as.integer(strtrim(vals, nchar(vals) - 3))

library(chron)
fun_chron <- function(vals) hours(times(paste0(vals, ":00")))

fun_lt <- function(vals) as.POSIXlt(vals, format="%H:%M")$hour

library(stringi)
fun_stri_sub <- function(vals) as.integer(stri_sub(vals, from = 1, to = -4))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun_substr(vals),
               fun_stri_sub(vals),      
               grab.hrs(vals),
               fun_strtrim(vals),
               fun_lt(vals),
               fun_chron(vals),
               unit = "relative", times = 5)
# Unit: relative
#               expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   fun_substr(vals)  2.186714  1.902074  2.015082  1.968542  1.945007  2.090236     5
# fun_stri_sub(vals)  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000     5
#     grab.hrs(vals)  2.656630  2.397918  2.687133  2.426223  2.446902  3.263962     5
#  fun_strtrim(vals) 31.177869 27.601380 26.009818 27.423562 17.902507 29.426989     5
#       fun_lt(vals) 47.296929 41.122287 42.266556 40.647465 30.539030 52.710992     5
#    fun_chron(vals)  5.594931  5.159192  5.961775  7.746242  5.286944  6.189742     5
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik for compiling all the methods into one. Very helpful in understanding the options.

Comment: substr is indeed good, I was able to reproduce the same benchmark results. Accepted as answer (and +1 for all others, which are equally valuable).

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this with the `times` function from the `chron` package:

```
library(chron)
vals <- c("9:46","11:06", "14:17", "19:53", "0:03", "3:56")
dat <- times(paste0(vals, ":00"))
hours(dat)
# [1]  9 11 14 19  0  3
```

If speed is important, you could extract the hours more quickly with a string manipulation:

```
grab.hrs <- function(vals) as.numeric(sub(pattern = ":.*", replacement = "",
                                      x = vals))
grab.hrs(vals)
# [1]  9 11 14 19  0  3
```

`times` and `as.POSIXlt` (from @tonytonov's solution) seem to be somewhat quicker than `as.ITime`, and the string manipulation is much quicker:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
microbenchmark(hours(times(paste0(vals, ":00"))),
               hours(as.ITime(vals)),
               as.POSIXlt(vals, format="%H:%M")$hour,
               grab.hrs(vals))
# Unit: microseconds
#                                     expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#        hours(times(paste0(vals, ":00"))) 174.544 184.9485 193.5630 204.6950 5047.195   100
#                    hours(as.ITime(vals)) 665.833 678.8790 705.6445 735.0525 3030.574   100
#  as.POSIXlt(vals, format = "%H:%M")$hour 158.264 169.8880 171.9670 180.1800  301.840   100
#                           grab.hrs(vals)  10.637  15.4540  20.0995  21.1285   55.985   100
```

Comment: +1! `as.numeric(sub(pattern = ":.*", replacement = "", x = vals)` may be even faster here.

Comment: @Henrik nice! I've updated with that one -- it indeed sped it up.

Answer (score 6):

Is this an option? This is a `base` solution.

```
as.POSIXlt(times, format="%H:%M")$hour
#[1]  9 11 14 19  0  3
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensible solution (Works well even if the time format changes).

Answer (score 6):

To really speed up, you can also just trim off the lsat 3 chars from the strings. It's faster than using `regex`.

```
as.numeric(strtrim(times, nchar(times) - 3)) 
## [1]  9 11 14 19  0  3
```

Here are benchmark results

```
Unit: microseconds
                                         expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
            hours(times(paste0(vals, ":00"))) 200.670 212.9720 218.7960 221.8420  352.370   100
                        hours(as.ITime(vals)) 453.174 478.9680 487.3805 496.7885 1607.321   100
      as.POSIXlt(vals, format = "%H:%M")$hour  41.278  46.4945  49.7310  51.3115   56.453   100
                               grab.hrs(vals)  12.352  15.4295  18.3850  20.3390   31.349   100
  as.numeric(gsub("(.*):.*", "\\\\1", times))  14.528  17.7225  20.6390  23.4530   53.683   100
 as.numeric(strtrim(times, nchar(times) - 3))   9.621  11.6605  12.7435  13.2520  147.446   100
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `stri_sub` function from the [stringi](http://stringi.rexamine.com) package and trim the last 3 characters like this:

```
require(stringi)
times <- c("9:46", "11:06", "14:17", "19:53", "0:03", "3:56")
stri_sub(times, from = 1, to = -4)
## [1] "9"  "11" "14" "19" "0"  "3"
```

If `from` and/or `to` parameters are negative then counting is done from the end of a string. So in this example the substring is from the first character to the fourth one but counting from the end of string.

Comment: It is really fast because it was written in pure C++, so it has to be fast :) As every single function from this package. Feel free to check! :)