# Faster way to get year from large data set in R

Tags: r, date

Is it any faster way to get the year from large data set (around 1GB) in R?

Currently I used `data$year <- format(as.Date(data$pickup_datatime), "%Y")` to get the year, but it took very long time.

Comment: Do both functions take a long time, or is it one or the other? You might try `lubridate::year()` instead of `format`.

Comment: Instead of parsing the dates, you may try `substr` or `stringi::stri_sub`, as I did here when grabbing hour: [Fastest way to extract hour from time (HH:MM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803212/fastest-way-to-extract-hour-from-time-hhmm/22806994#22806994). When posting a question about speed, it's good if you also provide easily reproducible data of sufficient size to try the code on. Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to extract hour from time (HH:MM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803212/fastest-way-to-extract-hour-from-time-hhmm)

Comment: ...or at least post some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

the `lubridate` package has a built-in function to get the year from a date-like object. Here's the use for your case:

```
data$year <- lubridate::year(data$pickup_datatime)
```